# Windows Server 2003 secondary DC issues

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003

I have some strange issues with my domain controller.
I have primary DC called 'netsun' with ADDS, DNS and DHCP, and secondary DC called 'ex_serv' with ADDS service and exchange.

So my primary DC is 'netsun', and the trouble is when my secondary DC (ex_serv) goes down, users start complaining about that they cant access they files located on another server for file sharing or login to their accounts - basically all kind of auth issues with domain user account. So i think that even if all roles located on primary DC - netsun, secondary DC still have some unseen roles or somethink like that.
I will glad for any help.

Here how it looks:

> toys.toy - domain name
>
> netsun - primary DC - 192.168.1.12
>
> ex_serv - secondary and exchange - 192.168.1.13

ping from any domain pc:

```
C:\Users\Admin>ping toys.toy

Pinging toys.toy [192.168.1.12] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 192.168.1.12: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

query from netsun

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>netdom query fsmo
Schema owner                netsun.toys.toy
Domain role owner           netsun.toys.toy
PDC role                    netsun.toys.toy
RID pool manager            netsun.toys.toy
Infrastructure owner        netsun.toys.toy
```

query from ex_serv

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>netdom query fsmo
Schema owner                netsun.toys.toy
Domain role owner           netsun.toys.toy
PDC role                    netsun.toys.toy
RID pool manager            netsun.toys.toy
Infrastructure owner        netsun.toys.toy
```

So i looks like netsun is responsible for all schemas and anythink, but if i shutdown ex_serv - users cant login to file shares and even sometimes can login to theis PCs

Sorry for bad english, i hope that i described it pretty well.
I will glad for any help, realy. I havent sleep already 16 hours trying to figure it out )
Any suggestions?

All what i need is to be sure that 'netsun' is reponsible for all 'domain things', because i'm doing preparations for migration to win server 2012.

Comment: The problem isn't with the FSMO placement. Are both DC's also DNS servers for your AD DNS zone? Do all of the clients and member servers have both DC/DNS servers configured as DNS servers? Do your DNS zones have the correct DNS records for both DC/DNS servers? Have you run DCDIAG?

Answer (score 2):

Check for dns config on client (first dns server1 and secondary server2 etc). 
Check domain fsmo problems (dcdiag and other tools).

Check time and date on dc. 
Because time is sometime a problem on physical server(motherboard battery down... ). 
And check ntp config on the two dc(time source).